# How can array variables be used as pointers?

Tags: c

```
int test[] = {1,2,3,4};

printf("%i",3[test]);
```

How is this the same as test[3]? 
I know that array variable can be used as a pointer to the first element and that can be used to refer to or point to the other variables in the array but how is this statement correct? 3 is not an array variable here.

Comment: Because `test[3]` is the same as `*(test + 3)` is the same as `*(3 + test)`.

Comment: `x[y]` is shorthand for `*(x + y)`, `+` being commutative it is the same as `*(y + x)` for which `y[x]` is shorthand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is `test[3]` is actually considered as `*(test+3)` which is same as `*(3+test)` because of around `+` the `3` and `test` commute. As a result `3[test]` is also possible. It doesn't matter if you write it `*(3+test)` or `*(test+3)` or `test[3]` and `3[test]`.

From [6.5.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2) C11 standard

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. *The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`*. Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

`E1[E2]` is indeed `*((E1)+(E2))` and we know binary addition is [**commutative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). So we can say that it is same as `*((E2)+(E1))` so can't we write it as `E2[E1]`. Yes we can and that's legal.

Comment: I do not exactly understand this commuting thing. Can you please explain it a little more?

Comment: @Nalin Did you sleep in math class? Addition is commutative, meaning that order does not matter. `1+5` is equal to `5+1`. When dealing with pointer arithmetic (arithmetic when a pointer is involved) the same applies.

Comment: @Pablo Yes I  know that. I was just confused about the use of [].

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%i` or `%d` it specifies a signed decimal integer. Then the value assigned for that integer is denoted by `3[test]`. Therefore here `%i` denotes the value of the 4th element of the array(because array pointer starts with 0)